# Mongodb, we can't go over 100 insert/sec on 200iops HDD

Tags: performance, hard-drive, hardware, mongodb, performance-tuning

Thanks in advance for your help, we get a strange behaviour in mongodb. So we have a cluster of 20 shards, each composed of 1 master and 2 slaves. This database has a heavy load of write only. However when looking at mongotop, there is more "getmore" than "insert" themselves. This is a big problem for performances as master hard disk are under heavy read and write. we can't even support 100 insert/sec per shard

[image]

[image]

This is not peak hour now, we went as high as 700 load average on a 40 core machine.

**EDIT 1:**

HDD information

[image]
[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Average object size is ~500 bytes

Comment: Please describe your disk subsystem.

Comment: Glad you added the edit but can you answer the question about your system please.

Comment: What do you want to know about the system exactly?

Comment: What are the disks plugged into?

Comment: I don't follow, could you be more specific?